# Is it possible to register a multi-dotted file extension?

Tags: c#, windows, registry

In our application, we have a file extension like this:

```
filename.applicationName.zip
```

Now I want to register its file extension

```
.applicationName.zip
```

**Q: It this possible at all?**

(I know how to register file extensions, that's not the point here)

Comment: If you know how to register extensions, why don't you try to register this one and see what happens?

Comment: @Trickery Trial and error isn't the way to go.

Comment: I want to understand how windows work.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan but it is a good way to learn.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan No, but having tried that and reporting the findings would be a good way of demonstrating effort in the question, thus improving it's quality.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

An extension is defined to be the characters that appear after the final dot in the filename. The file extension is determined by simple text processing. You start at the end of the filename and walk backwards until you find a dot.

Using your example, the file extension of `filename.applicationName.zip` is `zip`. You might think that the extension of your file is `applicationName.zip` but the system does not. And it's the system's rules that count.

Thus, a file extension cannot contain a dot. And so, whilst you could register a file extension with a dot, the system would never recognise any file as matching your extension.

Comment: This means that it's not possible to register such a file extension?

Comment: Well, I expect you could register such an extension. But since no file can have such an extension, what good would it do you? Your file's extension is `zip`.

Comment: Some reference to docs here would be awesome